# Critical Numbers And Extreme Values Of A Piecewise Function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Please determine the critical numbers and extreme values of the :
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2-2x-x^2, & -2\le x \le 0 \\
|x-2|, & 0<x<3 \\
\frac {1}{3}(x-2)^3, & 3\le x \le 4
\end{cases}
$$
I even know that the derivative of $f(x)$ is$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-2-2x, & -2\le x < 0 \\
\frac {x-2}{|x-2|}, & 0<x<3 \\
(x-2)^2, & 3< x \le 4
\end{cases}
$$
I think $x=0$ is the only critical number!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Amzoti I have already told that I think $x=0$ is the only critical number, I think $x=3$ is not critical number because that point is not differentiable at all.

Comment: @Amzoti I've revised my question, please make second thought.

Comment: Where does the derivative vanish? If the derivative is not defined at a given point, can you determine whether that point is a local maximum or minimum?

Comment: @FreeMind: Keep in mind that a critical point is either where the derivative is zero *or* where it is *undefined*.  Often a piecewise defined function, as here, may be continuous at the endpoints where segments of definition connect without being differentiable there.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

First notice that the function is continuous except at $x=3$.

Notice that the derivative vanishes at $x=-1$, that the left derivative does not equal the right derivative at $x=0$ and $x=2$, and since the function is not continuous at $x=3$, the derivative cannot exist there.

**Further Hint:**

Now, simply look at the function between these points:

a) at $x=-1$, there is a local maximum: $f(-2)=2$, $f(-1)=3$, and $f(0)=2$.

b) at $x=0$, the left derivative is $-2$ and the right derivative is $-1$.

c) at $x=2$, the left derivative is $-1$ and the right derivative is $+1$.

d) at $x=3$, the function jumps from $1$ to $\frac13$.

---

You should consider

$f(-2)=2\qquad$endpoint
$\color{#C00000}{f(-1)=3}\qquad$derivative is $0$
$\color{#C00000}{f(2)=0}\ \ \ \qquad$left derivative has different sign than right derivative
$f(3-)=1\qquad$left side of jump discontinuity
$f(3)=\frac13\ \,\qquad$right side of jump discontinuity
$f(4)=\frac83\ \,\qquad$endpoint

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Comment: My main confusion was about extrema at discontinuous point.

Comment: Could you please tell me why you tested the $x=3$, if $f$ is discontinuous at $x=3$ then it should not have any local maximum at $x=3$ since it's not continuous from left.Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Consider [the graph](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zdhzK.png) of the function [$\mathrm{sgn}(x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)$-x:[-1,1]\to(-1,1)$. It has its largest and smallest values near its discontinuity.

Comment: what I'm saying is , near discontinuous point the function cannot have extreme value, since we can approach the value at the discontinuous point as near as we want.

Comment: Depending on how the function is defined at the discontinuity, it might attain the maximum value, or only approach it as close as you want, but you should check what happens.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like there is a relative minimum from the right of x=3.  From the left, the function isn't defined at x=3, so we can't have a relative maximum.